# Android Java FATAL EXCEPTION java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to Android, know a little JAVA, but i want to learn and i keep doing tutorials. The idea of what i want to do is the following:
I have a rendered menu, for example:
 1. BIRDS 
 2. ROCKS 
 3. PLANTS
and when I press BIRDS I want to show pictures and a small description. The id's of the images and the description I keep in a xml. Like this:

```
<signs>
    <sign id="1_1" category="1">
        <name>desc1</name>
    </sign>
    <sign id="1_2" category="1">
        <name>desc2</name>
    </sign>
    <sign id="1_3_1" category="1">
        <name>desc3</name>
    </sign>
    <sign id="1_3_2" category="1">
        <name>desc4</name>
    </sign>
</signs>
```

the picture goes like sign_1_1.png, sign_1_2.png in drawables.

I made the gallery, it is showing, the description and images also are visible. I made that on image gallery Selected image to show the corresponding description in a TextView.
But when I tap i get a FATAL EXCEPTION:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22141): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(22141): at apcmag.examples.singleSignListItem$ImageAdapter.getView(singleSignListItem.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(22141):    at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:849)
E/AndroidRuntime(22141): at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryRightLtr(Gallery.java:803)
E/AndroidRuntime(22141):    at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryRight(Gallery.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime(22141):    at android.widget.Gallery.layout(Gallery.java:656)
E/AndroidRuntime(22141):    at android.widget.Gallery.onLayout(Gallery.java:351)
E/AndroidRuntime(22141):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
E/AndroidRuntime(22141):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
```

The code is:

```
package apcmag.examples;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class singleSignListItem extends Activity
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_sign_gallery);

        Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

        final Intent i = getIntent();
        final String REGEX = "/%%/";

        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");

        setTitle(product);

        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String [] products = i.getStringExtra("product_text").split(REGEX);
                Toast.makeText(singleSignListItem.this, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TextView show_intro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_intro);
                show_intro.setText(""+products[position]);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;


//        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
//                R.drawable.sign_1_1,
//                R.drawable.sign_1_1,
//                R.drawable.sign_1_1,
//                R.drawable.sign_1_1
//        };

        private Integer[] mImages = takePhotos();

        public Integer[] takePhotos (){
            Intent g = getIntent();
            String Reg = "/%%/";
            String Reg2 = "_%_";

            String dataList = g.getStringExtra("product_text");
            String [] datastring = dataList.split(Reg);

            Integer[] imageResource = new Integer[20];

            String[] dd = null;

            for(int k = 0; k<datastring.length;k++){
                dd = datastring[k].split(Reg2);

            String imagename = "sign_"+dd[0];

            imageResource[k] = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", getPackageName());

            }

            return imageResource;

        }

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
            mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(115, 200));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

            return i;
        }
    }

}
```

I can't get what the problem is for hours, and i have some ideas that it might be here:

```
 i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(115, 200));
```

but i am not so sure what to do

**UPDATE**

Actually i found the problem:

On Line 77 I was Initializing ImageResource with size 20

```
Integer[] imageResource = new Integer[20];
```

but the splited datastring had just 4 elements

```
String [] datastring = dataList.split(Reg);
```

so mImages variable

```
 private Integer[] mImages = takePhotos();
```

would have 20 elements from which 16 would be null
and in the end

```
i.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
```

it could not render the null elements and it crashed.

So there i have another question:

If i don't know the size of the posible Integer[] how do I initiliaze and push in it elements ? With List ?

Comment: The error is flagged on line 130 of singleSignListItem which is 126 lines long as you've posted it. Which line of code is line 130?

Comment: Oh, I deleted some commented lines. So now the error is here:  i.setImageResource(mImages[position]);

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and step through your code until you hit the breakpoint.  Examine mImages.  How long is it?  What is the value of position?

Comment: mImages is Integere[20] as it was initialized, position is 0;

Comment: Then, assuming that the line referenced in the stack trace is indeed i.setImageResource(), then mImages[0] must be null.  I suspect this line imageResource[k] = getResources().getIdentifier(imagename, "drawable", getPackageName());  The statement is possibly returning null.  Is imagename correct?  Does it match exactly what's in drawables?

Comment: so there are only a few possibilities there. i is null; mImages is null or mImages[position] is null. Instead of passing it directly to setImageResource declare a variable so you can confirm it isn't null.

Comment: Actually I think i found the problem, I was initializing mImages = Integer[20]; but pushed in just 4 elements. The others were null, so it was rendering 4 normal images other would crash.

Comment: @doomie If you got it working you can post your own solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Got it working, posted as update! Thanks!

Comment: Cool, accept your own answer and get extra points.  Then use a List of some sort, see "Java generics" for details but, for now try an ArrayList<String>.  Then you can add however many you need and .size() will tell you how many you have for later use in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found the problem:

On Line 77 I was Initializing ImageResource with size 20

> Integer[] imageResource = new Integer[20];

but the splited datastring had just 4 elements

```
String [] datastring = dataList.split(Reg);
```

so mImages variable

```
 private Integer[] mImages = takePhotos();
```

would have 20 elements from which 16 would be null and in the end

```
i.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
```

it could not render the null elements and it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

public Object getItem(int position) { return position; } public long getItemId(int position) { return position; } check the return type . I think both will be int.

Comment: if these the selected answer then click accepted ,it will help others.

Comment: I already found the problem! Thanks for your opinion! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

There is error in this line:

```
for(int k = 0; k<datastring.length;k++){
  dd = datastring[k].split(Reg2);
```

I think it will do  the work for you to do this:

```
dd = datastring.split(Reg2);
```

Comment: `datastring` is actually an array. Maybe the name could be be a bit more obvious, but that is what the `[k]` is for.

Comment: Actually I am looping through datastring and split the element. Otherwise if I change that eclipse is showing me an error.

Comment: "Developer", the OP is splitting a string, then further splitting those strings.  This code is fine.

Comment: i think you should use only one regex that will do the work for two. You should change the Reg to  "[/%%/]+"  .Look if it works ,if not tell.

Comment: and please tell me what you want to do in the regex . I mean by splitting what you want to get?

Comment: The regex is ok, the variables look fine in debugger.

Comment: public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
check the return type . I think both will be int.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks for your opinion!

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is String[] dd = null; code. u must initialize dd variable

Comment: He is using `dd = datastring[k].split(Reg2);` to set up `dd` each time through the loop.